# Windows Authentication with IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I using **Windows Authentication** with IIS 7, I need the prompt don't show or display. 
What is the correct way for the prompt don´t display.

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat difficult to understand what you are asking.
But I'm taking a stab at it and assume that you have set up a web site using `Windows Authentication`, and when you browse to it with a web browser you get a login dialog asking for username and password.
Is my assumption correct?

The reason for this could be a list of things.
Unfortunately you are not mentioning anything whether you are using a intranet based web site or an internet facing web site.
If it is the former, then there's hope, if the latter not so much.

Assuming that you are within boundaries of a corporate network, an intranet solution.
First off, make sure you are using a web browser that support Windows Authentication. Microsoft Internet Explorer is a good start. If using IE, make sure that it is set to `Enable Windows Authentication` in `Tools->Internet Options->Advanced`.
And that the host name you are accessing is part of the Local Intranet Zone in the Security Tab of IE. That way, you can take advantage of the Automatic logon functionality.

Second, if you are not using Impersonation on the web site, make sure that the account running the application pool has all the necessary permissions to all needed resources. (Like files it may need to access, DB access an so forth.)

If you are using Impersonation, make sure that the account running the browser session has all the necessary permission to all eventual resources your web application may access. (See previous)

If you are using an internet facing web site, then sorry, you are out of luck.

You know, if your question would have been more specific, you would have given a much better answer.

Comment: This was a pretty good answer to a vague question! Does the Web server also have to be in the "Intranet Zone" for this to work?

Comment: @theglauber, yes if you want automatic login. I'll update the answer